# Php/Mysqli error, Empty page as output

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying to identify the error for two days and  i am still not getting the error, it just shows plain/empty page. Can anyone please help me identify what is the problem or what am i doing wrong! Even if i type the query wrong in the script it does not show error.

```
<?php

    include_once("connection.php");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM information";
    $rs=$conn->query($sql);
    if($rs===false)
    {
        $errmsg='Incorrect Query : ' . $sql . ' Error : ' . $conn->error;
        trigger_error($errmsg, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<table>");
        while($arr=$rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo("<tr>");
            echo("<td>".$arr['id']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['firstName']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['middleName']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['lastName']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['rollNumber']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['contactNumber']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['emailId']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['gender']."</td>"
                ."<td>".$arr['department']."</td>"
                ."<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$arr['id']."'>Delete</a></td>"
                ."<td><a href='update.php?id=".$arr['id']."'>Update</a></td>");
            echo '</tr>';

        }   
        echo("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href="insert.php"> Add New </a></td>");
        echo("</tr>");
        echo("</table>");
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>

/*---------------------------connection.php-------------------------- */
<?php

define("HOSTNAME","localhost");
define("USERNAME","root");
define("PASSWORD","root");
define("DB_NAME","students");

$conn = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($conn->connect_errno)
{
    echo("<br> Unable to connect with database. <br>
        Error Code : (".$conn->connect_errno.") <br>
        Error Details : ". $conn->connect_error); 
    die('<br> Final Status : Not Connected');
}
?>
```

Comment: can you give code of connection.php

Comment: Error in this Line "        echo("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href="insert.php"> Add New </a></td>");"

Comment: smoke, code is updated with connection.php script

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in this line `unexpected double quotes` in your `anchor tag`

```
 echo("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href="insert.php"> Add New </a></td>");
```

It would be

```
echo("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href='insert.php'> Add New use of single quote for link </a></td>");
```

Comment: it does not work, it's still the same. Even if i type the query wrong it does not show error.

Comment: that's the only syntax mistake  in your code for blank scree may be some error with of your query and connection

Comment: i have also added connection code, it works well with insert page, but i don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: still it show blank page to you. Or some other error

Comment: check your console and use die step by step to find out the error

Comment: it is still the same.

Comment: inside while loop `print_r($arr);die();` and check what it show??

Comment: still page is still blank, it does not show me error even if i manipulate the query, is my method to check error of query correct?

Comment: echo `$sql="SELECT * FROM information";` at first line after `  include_once("connection.php");` check what it return

Comment: still the same, its a blank page.

Comment: May be problem is with connection fiel

Comment: i worked all day on it and i don't think i can get it to work anymore :(